# Standard error of a hypotenuse

Tags: standard-error

I'm trying to calculate the standard error $\sigma_{h}$ of hypotenuse $h$ of a right angle triangle given sides of length $a$ and $b$ with SEs $\sigma_{a}$ and $\sigma_b$. I don't want to use any of the internal angles because these are inferred, whereas $a$ and $b$ are directly observed. Let's assume errors are normally distributed.

I'm hastily revising rules on propagation of errors, but does the following formulation make sense?

The expected value of $h$ should be $\sqrt{(a^2 + b^2)}$.

Errors for $a^2$ and $b^2$ should be $2 \frac{\sigma_{a}}{a}$ and $2 \frac{\sigma_{b}}{b}$.

Summing those gives errors for $a^2+b^2$ as $\sqrt{(2 \frac{\sigma_{a}}{a})^2 + (2 \frac{\sigma_{b}}{b})^2}$

If errors for $h^2$ are $2 \frac{\sigma_h}{h}$, then

$2 \frac{\sigma_h}{h} = \sqrt{(2 \frac{\sigma_{a}}{a})^2 + (2 \frac{\sigma_{b}}{b})^2}$

hence

$\sigma_h = \frac{h}{2}\sqrt{(2 \frac{\sigma_{a}}{a})^2 + (2 \frac{\sigma_{b}}{b})^2}$